# I am not a part of a plant. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am not a part of the plant,
>
> But a part of me is plant part,
>
> I am there in you,
>
> Without me sweet and sour is same.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Taste buds. Buds are also a plant part, but taste buds aren't. Without them, you can't tell what is sweet or what is sour.